# PHP Проверка return функции

Tags: php

есть функция

```
function boroda() {...}
```

которая возвращает или false или строку.
как красиво сделать проверку не фолс ли, если нет сделать echo?
пробывал: $aa=boroda()?(print $aa):die('ERROR'); - работет коряво, к тому же выдает ошибку типа notice, что аа не определена

```
if(boroda()) {
 echo boroda();
}
```

//вообще бред ибо тогда функция вызывается 2 раза, а возвращает она у меня будь-здоров данных...

```
$aa=boroda();
if($aa) {
   echo $aa;
}
```

Не нравится, так как громоздко и еще лишнюю переменную объявляем.
Подскажите как выкрутится, желательно с синтаксисом statement?true:false

Comment: Почему не хотите выводить в любом случае? `FALSE` просто ничего не выведет.

    echo boroda();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут `$aa=boroda()?(print $aa):die('ERROR');` действительно ошибка. Правильно будет вот так:

```
 ($aa=boroda())?(print $aa):die('ERROR');
```

Для тех, кто будет читать мой ответ и не понимать, немного разжую:
Код `$aa=boroda()?(print $aa):die('ERROR');` видит php как
`$aa = результат_некого_вырожения` поэтому необходимо добавить скобки
`($aa=boroda()) ? (print $aa) : die('ERROR');`. Теперь пхп его прочитает так как нам нужно.

А красиво будет так:

```
print ($resultBoroda=boroda()) !== false ? $resultBoroda : throw new Exception('Boroda return false');
```

Удачи.

Answer (score 3):

```
if (($aa=boroda())!==false) print $aa; else die('ERROR');
```